# Tax Class Change Returns in Germany

Tags: germany, taxes, blue-card, tax-deductions

I have EU Blue Card and live in Germany. I married a few months ago and will apply for the family reunion visa since my wife not living in the EU. I know that I can't change my tax class from 1(single) to 5(married with a less earning partner) since the spouse living abroad.

My question is when she gets her family reunion visa, will we earn any sort of tax returns for the period from the day we married to the day she has her visa?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The day your wife takes up residence in Germany.

Answer (score 0):

Your real taxes have nothing to do with the class that is used for preliminary deductions.
When (If!) you file your taxes, the will be calculated based on your real situation (married or not etc), and any overpayments are reimbursed (and any underpayments are due).

Note that in Germany, it's nearly impossible to underpay, and you are not required to file your taxes, meaning *they gladly keep your overpayment if you don't ask for it back*. So make sure to file your taxes.

Comment: Especially if your tax class changes, chances are 99% that by filing your tax return you will get money back.

Comment: And chances are 100% you will be in trouble if you owe them money and do not file.

Comment: quantum, says who? You will eventually pay your taxes. Just don’t lie.